# How to sum data by in a category in Spotfire

Tags: sum, expression, categories, spotfire, qualifiers

What would the custom expression be to sum data by a category, for each site.

Using the data below, I would like to Sum[X] for only values with category blue, for each site

What I have so far is Sum([X]) OVER [Site] --> Where / how do I put in the category qualifier?

[image: Example Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I found works best is: Sum(If([Category]="Blue",[X],0)) OVER ([Site])

Answer (score 2):

the `Intersect()` function is a perfect fit here. it creates a hierarchy based on however many columns you list. more info in [the documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_over_functions.htm).

anyway, try the following:

```
Sum([X]) OVER (Intersect([Site], [Category]))
```

---

To do the same for only a single category, you can use an expression like

```
Sum(If([Category]="Blue",[X],0)) OVER ([Site])
```

This will leave a null/empty value when [X] is not "Blue" (case sensitive so beware!).

If you have multiple values, you can replace the condition with

```
If([X] in ("Blue", "Nurple", "Taupe"), ...)
```

Comment: I see, but how would I specify only the Blue category though? I do not want to sum any data that is from the Red category. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok I misunderstood. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Niko,  I had to modify your expression because it wasn't going through, turns out its a variation of what you suggested and what I found works best is: 

Sum(If([Category]="Blue",[X],0)) OVER ([Site])

Thanks for the initial input though, got me most of the way!

Comment: that's correct. sorry; posted via mobile and before my coffee! glad you got it solved :)